# Can we use time.sleep function in multinline print

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a script that had a multi-line print functions like this

```
print """ Example
Example
Example
..
"""
```

I wanna know is there any way we can add time.sleep() function in multi-line print or get a similar functionality like sleep function I want it to look like this.

```
print """ Example
time.sleep(1)
Example
time.sleep(1)
Example
time.sleep(1)
..
"""
```

But this wont work as python just prints time.sleep and i really don't want single-line print command

Sorry if this is a dumb question

Comment: No. You are printing a multi-line string. The interpreter is not going to guess which lines happen to be Python syntax and magically execute them

Comment: yes yes i know that is there any other function that might work or should i work with single line print?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to use a loop:

```py
times = 3
for i in range(0, times):
    print('Example')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the most efficient way of doing this but it's a way that will work.

```
from time import sleep

print("example")
sleep(1)
print("example")
sleep(1)
print("example")
sleep(1)
```

Although a loop would work like the previous answer that could be an issue when you have different strings.